# Will Ubuntu prompt me for consensual 14.04.x download?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I just did fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.1 on my desktop. Naturally, there are many updates available in Software Updater for me to download, but it's very important for my WiFi chipset that I update no later than Ubuntu 14.04.3 (it will stop working beyond that release, and I won't get Internet).

What I'm wondering is whether it's safe to download all of the updates currently available in Software Updater, and whether Ubuntu will give me a prompt for whether I want to download the next 14.04.x release. I would really like to keep my Internet access.

Thank you.

Comment: What happened with your WIFI?  I don't understand why an update to Ubuntu would affect that.  Please let me know.

Comment: I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 (previously on 12.04), and my WiFi stopped working. I asked some questions on the Ubuntu Forums, and was informed that several others with my WiFi chipset (the Qualcomm Atheros AR928X) weren't getting Internet on 16.04 either. Apparently the last time it was known to work was on Ubuntu 14.04.3. You can view the thread I created (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2326224&p=13496764#post13496764), and also the bug I filed (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1586875) if you like. Thanks for your swift response though!

Comment: No problem, I have been lucky on my machines, and have had no issues like that.  I have found by reading that sometimes if you update the kernel to a newer version it fixes some of these issue, just FYI for next time.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Although I'm not going to try Ubuntu 16.04 again unless I see in written confirmation that my WiFi adapter is now supported (it was that much of a headache). Anyway, thanks for your helpfulness!

Comment: No problem, and good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard updates are fine, and in my experience the updater software will tell you when there is a new release, and the option to install it or not.

Comment: The updates finished installing, and it looks like they actually did upgrade me to 14.04.4 without my consent. BUT, I still seem to have Internet connection. So, as long as it holds out, it should be okay. Just thought it was odd how Ubuntu didn't prompt me about the release upgrade.

Comment: I'm sorry, It would seem to me though that if this version works for you, I would think that with the minor upgrades it should still work.

Comment: Heh, it's okay. As long as it doesn't start to malfunction, I think it will be okay. I appreciate your responsiveness!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I cant add comment.

Your WiFi driver problem is probably related to kernel version.
Ubuntu LTS (14.04 and 14.04.1) initial release installs with v3.13 series kernel, updates to running system keep kernel at v3.13 level, changing kernel to newer version requires conscious act on behalf of admin (ie. [LTS Kernel Upgrade](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_-_Trusty_Tahr) ).

You'll be safe as long as You won't install any of LTSEnablementStack packages (and please don't install Utopic kernel v3.16, this kernel is theoretically newer than v3.13, but its support will end in August 2016, while v3.13 will be supported till Trusty's End of Life).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That is good to know. How will I know when Ubuntu wants me to upgrade kernels? (I've already installed all available updates, including Ubuntu 14.04.4, and my Internet is still working so far...)

Comment: Hi there, I'm still curious about your comment about Linux kernel versions. How do I make sure my Ubuntu 14.04.4 stays on kernel version 3.13, and doesn't upgrade to anything higher? (i.e. Where are the LTS Enablement Stack packages so I can avoid them?) Thanks!

Comment: uname -a will give you current kernel version. Link from my post will give you answers to LTS Enablement Stack questions. Avoid installing packages with linux lts & releaseName in name, where releaseName is utopic, vivid, wily or xenial. 14.04.4 installs by default with v4.2 kernel, but upgrade from 14.04.1 does not bump kernel version it installs patched v3.13.

Comment: Cool, think I've got it now. Just don't install any release upgrades with a name in it like 'Utopic' or any LTSes. Thanks!

Comment: Not like this, only packages with both lts and releaseName in their name will bump up version of kernel and x server.